How to add maven goals to visual studio code run/debug configuration?
In IntelliJ IDEA there is such a concept as a "maven goal".

These are able to be run "before launch", meaning before running the main class configuration in question.
When I look at Visual Studio's support for launch configuration options, I see no such option for adding maven goals, or any pre-launch command options at all. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configuration-options
Is this a feature Visual Studio code does or will support in the future? And if so, how do I do it? At the end of the day I just need multiple other maven projects to be installed before running the specific maven project in question.
IntelliJ only needs the path to the other maven project, and the maven command to run (e.g. install), so hopefully Visual Studio Code has some similar feature.

There's a parameter called "preLaunchTask" that can accept the "label" name of a task. So you can add the raw maven install commands as a task, and inject the label for said task into "preLaunchTask".
Using "preLaunchTasks" and Naming a Task in Visual Studio Code
Then, when you press "run" it will run the task first.
I'm not accepting this because there should be better options, and Visual Studio Code simply needs to do better than this.

Hello, if you use the task.json file in vscode to create an array of tasks. Is it possible to get the desired effect by operating according to the document?

yeah thats the crux of this answer

Do you want a new option to choose a different maven project before running?

I'm not following?

I'm sorry, I mean that do you want the feature to provide an option to select different Maven projects before running the project?

yeah that would be more user friendly!

I think that's a really good idea. But sorry, I'm not sure if you're looking forward to running the specified maven project. Similar to selecting the maven project you want to run in JAVA PROJECTS. Or something else, can you describe something else that's relevant? Thank you so much.
